# MFC: How to add clear button inside CEdit?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, cedit

I need to add a clear button inside the `CEdit` control like this:

[image]

And I used `CMFCEditBrowseCtrl`, as described in this article:
[MFC Feature Pack - `CMFCEditBrowseCtrl`](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35722/MFC-Feature-Pack-CMFCEditBrowseCtrl).

But the problem is that it shows a very small icon on monitors with high pixel density:

[image]

I tried to set a big icon, but the button remains narrow:

[image]

Could you please advice some solution?

Comment: Get a lower resolution monitor, then you'll be fine!

Comment: I prefer high resolution monitors, and some other users of my app.

Comment: You would probably have to override the class and do some custom rendering. I have the same issue with my menu item bitmaps. They are all 16 x 16 and for UHD users the show really small.

Comment: I was joking of course.  The code you're using is obviously not DPI-aware, you'll need to fix that.

Comment: What would be the solution? Getting rid of the icon, replacing with another one or showing existing proportional to the size of the button?

Comment: JohnCz, I tried to set a big icon, but the button remains narrow (I've updated my post).

Comment: This should show that MFC is an evolutionary dead end, try using WinUI3 instead, it's a modern UI library that supports high DPI screens out of the box.

Comment: Could you give some example of a user friendly and functional app on WinUI3? It seems to me that Microsoft continues the path of strange Windows 8 UIs.